# "No versions available for io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.13.1] within specified range" error when I add firebase-admin maven dependency in Eclipse

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to add firebase-admin dependency in my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>6.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to build my project using "clean install" command, I get following error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Communication Manager 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://192.168.1.4:8081/artifactory/libs-release/com/google/firebase/firebase-admin/6.6.0/firebase-admin-6.6.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: http://192.168.1.4:8081/artifactory/libs-release/com/google/firebase/firebase-admin/6.6.0/firebase-admin-6.6.0.pom (21 KB at 44.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.498 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-02T11:43:59+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project communicationmgr: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.server:communicationmgr:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:jar:6.6.0 -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:jar:0.61.0-beta -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.43.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.13.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.13.1]: No versions available for io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.13.1] within specified range -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I tried by explicitly adding the dependency for grpc-core :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This jar got downloaded to my local repository, but still the same error persists for firebase-admin.

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by deleting the maven-metadata out of the local repo directories (for the relevant dependencies).

i.e:

```
user_dir\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-api

maven-metadata-central.xml
maven-metadata-central.xml.sha1
resolver-status.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by overriding `grpc-core` in dependency management:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The order is important. Hope this helps.

Comment: It did not work for me. I finally resolved it by excluding dependency on grpc-core from firebase-admin and including it explicitly

Comment: @ShobhanaSriram your comment helped a lot please look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122445/maven-could-not-resolve-dependencies-on-google-firebase