# maven could not resolve dependencies on google firebase

Tags: java, firebase, maven

Am running `mvn clean install` on my gitlab ci/cd docker image and it throws the following error below.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bootstrap.service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sheeft:bootstrap.service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:jar:6.10.0 -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:jar:1.9.0 -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.79.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.21.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.21.0]: No versions available for io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.21.0] within specified range -> [Help 1]

So I tried the following in my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sheeft</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap.service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Sheeft Bootstrap Service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.23.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
                <version>[1.23.0]</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 2fa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerogear-otp-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.inlaks</groupId>
            <artifactId>inlaks-util-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>[1.23.0]</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

so the error is a bit different now but it is weird

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bootstrap.service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sheeft:bootstrap.service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.23.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:[1.23.0]: No versions available for io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:[1.23.0] within specified range -> [Help 1]

what is weird about the above error is that it actually downloaded the dependency as seen below

**Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/1.23.0/grpc-api-1.23.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-api/1.23.0/grpc-api-1.23.0.pom (0 B at 0 B/s)**

Comment: make sure you have these dependencies in your maven repository

Comment: @DevDio they are there I run mvn CLI options compile and it builds successfully.

Comment: Possible duplication of  [No versions available for grpc:grpc-corejar1.13.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002053/no-versions-available-for-io-grpcgrpc-corejar1-13-1-within-specified-range). Could also just be that when you run it on your docker image you not reaching your maven repo.

Comment: @Ambro-r I have updated the question, I looked at the link you shared and it helped a lot. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly refere to grpc-api versio 1.21.1 which prefent transient dependecny load from grpc-core 1.23 with related version. Why do you want them different?
If you wanna keep them like this you have to exclude grpc-api from grpc-core.

But easier way to handle it is keep one version for api and core.

Maven range syntax: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html

For Core module it's only strict version compatibility defined as:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
<artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
<version>[1.23.0]</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: kindly check my edit, because I tried what you just said but I still get the same issue.

Comment: I mean when you specify dependant artifact with different versions you tell Maven to find versions in range. From 1.21.1 to 1.23.0 in your case. So you have to assume that grpc-core has  compatibility range set as [1.21.x, 1.23.x) which is not true as you can find in POM in your links from central.

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify ranges a bit.

Comment: it didn't work.. I found the dependency in my lib central repository but it just not finding it.

Comment: Mate, it would work because maven would not allow to use different versions. Remove you -api section completly or update to 1.23.0.

Comment: I have pasted my entire pom, kindly let me know what am doing wrong. I don't understand you.

Comment: Nothing, apart i had too comment out your build section (no main class) anf inlaks-util-lib as not available - your pom is BUILD SUCESSFULL for maven 3.5.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200076/discussion-between-alex-davies-and-alexgera).

Comment: I have it working now, I had to exclude all the failing dependecies